# а возможно ли посмотреть количество оперативной памяти средствами javascript?

Tags: javascript

а возможно ли посмотреть количество оперативной памяти средствами javascript?

Comment: зависит от окружения. в самом языке нет таких функций.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду память сервера или клиента?

Comment: В любом случае - нет)

Comment: количество мегабайт на физической планке памяти пользовательского компьютера.

Answer (score 1):

В браузере - только в некоторых и то при условии что пользователь понизит уровень безопасности.

В node.js - есть соответствующие модули, например https://www.npmjs.com/package/os-monitor